# css closing sidebar when clicking in the main window

Tags: html, css

Hello there I searched for other people who has the same problem as me but I couldn't implement their problem to mine so I want to close the sidebar when clicking outside the sidebar.

```css
html {
    background-color: #161618;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#menuToggle
{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #7e7e7e;
  font-family: 'Microsoft Yahei';
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#menuToggle a:hover
{
  color: white;
}


#menuToggle input
{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 2px;
  
  cursor: pointer;
  
  opacity: 0; 
  z-index: 2;
  
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
#menuToggle span
{
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  
  z-index: 1;
  
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child
{
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #FCFCFC;
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3)
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}
#menu
{
  position: fixed;
  width: fit-content;
  background-color: #141414;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 15px rgb(5, 5, 5);
  height: 1400px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}
#menu li
{
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul
{
  transform: none;
}
.github:hover {
  filter: invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(308deg) brightness(101%) contrast(101%);
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
      <div id="menuToggle">
        <input type="checkbox" />

        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <ul id="menu">
          <a href="loading.html"><li>Home</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
          <a href="index.html"><li>Info</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
          <a href="#"><li><svg class="github" style="position:absolute;fill: #7e7e7e;width:35px;height:35px;margin-top: 275%;margin-left: 25%;padding:0%;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 0c-6.626 0-12 5.373-12 12 0 5.302 3.438 9.8 8.207 11.387.599.111.793-.261.793-.577v-2.234c-3.338.726-4.033-1.416-4.033-1.416-.546-1.387-1.333-1.756-1.333-1.756-1.089-.745.083-.729.083-.729 1.205.084 1.839 1.237 1.839 1.237 1.07 1.834 2.807 1.304 3.492.997.107-.775.418-1.305.762-1.604-2.665-.305-5.467-1.334-5.467-5.931 0-1.311.469-2.381 1.236-3.221-.124-.303-.535-1.524.117-3.176 0 0 1.008-.322 3.301 1.23.957-.266 1.983-.399 3.003-.404 1.02.005 2.047.138 3.006.404 2.291-1.552 3.297-1.23 3.297-1.23.653 1.653.242 2.874.118 3.176.77.84 1.235 1.911 1.235 3.221 0 4.609-2.807 5.624-5.479 5.921.43.372.823 1.102.823 2.222v3.293c0 .319.192.694.801.576 4.765-1.589 8.199-6.086 8.199-11.386 0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12z"/></svg></li></a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

as I should I have tried to solve the problem on my own and I did stuff with js with body onclick= ... but I am not that familiar with js and I don't know if it would work

Comment: what you asking for requires an onlick trigger or eventlistener -> So all possible solutions will come down to scripting: `document.querySelector("#menuToggle input").checked = false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your toggle menu works by checking/unchecking a `checkbox`. This can only be done by clicking on the input element (incl. all child elements) itself or by clicking on the linked label.

None of that applies if you clicking outside that specific element. As such you require a script to listen for click events outside of that element. [here you find a reference to this code](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/event+listener+for+when+you+click+outside+of+an+element)

Last but not least to finish the code from the reference you can use:
`document.querySelector("#menuToggle input").checked = false;` to uncheck the checkbox in question to close it.

```js
var ignoreElement = document.querySelector("#menuToggle");

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var clickElement = ignoreElement.contains(event.target);
  if (!clickElement) {
    document.querySelector("#menuToggle input").checked = false;
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #161618;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #7e7e7e;
  font-family: 'Microsoft Yahei';
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#menuToggle a:hover {
  color: white;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

#menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #FCFCFC;
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: fit-content;
  background-color: #141414;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 15px rgb(5, 5, 5);
  height: 1400px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
}

#menu li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#menuToggle input:checked~ul {
  transform: none;
}

.github:hover {
  filter: invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(308deg) brightness(101%) contrast(101%);
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <div id="menuToggle">
    <input type="checkbox" />

    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <ul id="menu">
      <a href="loading.html">
        <li>Home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>About</li>
      </a>
      <a href="index.html">
        <li>Info</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Contact</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li><svg class="github" style="position:absolute;fill: #7e7e7e;width:35px;height:35px;margin-top: 275%;margin-left: 25%;padding:0%;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 0c-6.626 0-12 5.373-12 12 0 5.302 3.438 9.8 8.207 11.387.599.111.793-.261.793-.577v-2.234c-3.338.726-4.033-1.416-4.033-1.416-.546-1.387-1.333-1.756-1.333-1.756-1.089-.745.083-.729.083-.729 1.205.084 1.839 1.237 1.839 1.237 1.07 1.834 2.807 1.304 3.492.997.107-.775.418-1.305.762-1.604-2.665-.305-5.467-1.334-5.467-5.931 0-1.311.469-2.381 1.236-3.221-.124-.303-.535-1.524.117-3.176 0 0 1.008-.322 3.301 1.23.957-.266 1.983-.399 3.003-.404 1.02.005 2.047.138 3.006.404 2.291-1.552 3.297-1.23 3.297-1.23.653 1.653.242 2.874.118 3.176.77.84 1.235 1.911 1.235 3.221 0 4.609-2.807 5.624-5.479 5.921.43.372.823 1.102.823 2.222v3.293c0 .319.192.694.801.576 4.765-1.589 8.199-6.086 8.199-11.386 0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12z"/></svg></li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```